# Outlook for Mac 2011 - How to sync with iCal (Google Calendar)?

Tags: ical, ms-office, google-calendar

This seems to be a common problem, but I couldn't find any solutions.

> I want to sync my Google Calendar with Outlook 2011

I tried this solution:

1. Sync Google Calendar with iCal
2. Then sync iCal with Outlook

I want to get my Google events into Outlook.

But I have a Problem:

1. Works fine. All my Google events are in iCal
2. Outlook won't show my iCal events. I did it with this [solution](http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/outlook/item/748ea995-465e-4c40-88d2-7669c7f37a0d)

What can I do as syncing directly from Outlook to Google isn't possible.

> Further Information:
>
> - Add an event in iCal -> shows up in Outlook
> - Add an event in Outlook -> doesn't show up in iCal

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do here, perhaps you could clarify in an edit?

I have intrepreted that you have Google cal synced with iCal, but want to sync iCal with Outlook.

You can sync iCal with Outlook. The full instructions are on microsofts [Outlook for mac support page](http://mac2.microsoft.com/help/office/14/en-us/outlook/item/748ea995-465e-4c40-88d2-7669c7f37a0d)

Comment: Prior to OS X 10.9, you can sync Outlook for Mac and iCal/Calendar using Sync Services. As of OS X 10.9 Mavericks, Sync Services is no longer available and this approach will not work any longer.

Answer (score 0):

The sync page referred to in the above answer had been removed from the Microsoft page.  All of the references on the MS page say that since os x doesn't support CalDAV you can't sync your mac cal with outlook 2011.

Drives everyone go Google if your a gmail user.